# Hard Time in understanding the Scala code which returns indices of the two numbers

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am having a hard time understanding *m.get* and *m+(x._1 -> x._2)* in below code ,can anyone let me know what does it do

```
object Solution {
    def twoSum(nums: Array[Int], target: Int): Array[Int] = {
      nums.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int,Int])((m,x)=>
      {
          if(m.get(target - x._1)==None)
              m+(x._1 -> x._2)
        else
            return Array(m.getOrElse(target-x._1, -1), x._2)
    })
    null
  }
}
```

This code  returns indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

Comment: `m` is a `Map`. `m.get(key)` retrieves a value from the `Map` wrapped in an `Option`. If the `Map` contains the specified key the result is `Some(value)` else the result is `None`. `m+(k->v)` adds a new key->value pair to the `Map`. (Note: That's not good/idiomatic Scala code.)

Comment: That code is by far not idiomatic in **Scala**. Anyways, the `get`, as the [**documentation**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#get(key:K):Option[V]) explains, is attempting to extract a value from the map given its key, however since the key may not exists, it returns the value wrapped in an **Option**.

Comment: Finally, the `m + (x._1, x._2)` is adding a new _key-value_ pair to the map. The `->` creates a new tuple, and the `._1` & `._2` are accessing the elements of the tuple `x` _(so if you have a little bit more brain than the person who wrote the code, you would noticed that all that was unnecessary, as it is exactly the same as `m + x`)_.

Comment: thank you for clear explaination @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few different (better?) ways to get the same result (essentially the same).

If you want all index pairs whose values sum to the target.

```
def twoSum(nums :Array[Int], target :Int) :Iterator[Seq[Int]] =
  nums.indices
      .combinations(2)
      .filter{case Seq(a,b) => nums(a) + nums(b) == target}

twoSum(Array(3,5,11,2,13,9), 41)  //returns empty Iterator
twoSum(Array(3,5,11,2,13,9), 14)  //returns Iterator(Seq(0, 2), Seq(1, 5))
```

If you want just the first pair that sum to the target (with early termination).

```
def twoSum(nums :Array[Int], target :Int) :Option[Seq[Int]] =
  nums.indices
      .combinations(2)
      .find{case Seq(a,b) => nums(a) + nums(b) == target}

twoSum(Array(3,5,11,2,13,9), 41)  //returns None
twoSum(Array(3,5,11,2,13,9), 14)  //returns Some(Seq(0, 2))
```

If you want to avoid the `Option` and just return an empty collection if no 2 values sum to the target.

```
def twoSum(nums :Array[Int], target :Int) :Seq[Int] =
  nums.indices
      .combinations(2)
      .find{case Seq(a,b) => nums(a) + nums(b) == target}
      .getOrElse(Seq())

twoSum(Array(3,5,11,2,13,9), 41)  //returns Seq()
twoSum(Array(3,5,11,2,13,9), 14)  //returns Seq(0, 2)
```

Comment: why i am getting error as Line 21: error: type mismatch; (in solution.scala)

Comment: All three solutions were tested (Scala 2.13.1) before being posted. Notice that the return type is different for each solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more efficient and idiomatic way to solve that problem.

```
def twoSum(nums: ArraySeq[Int], target: Int): Option[(Int, Int)] = {
  val allIndexes = for {
    i <- Iterator.range(start = 0, end = nums.length)
    j <- Iterator.range(start = i + 1, end = nums.length)
  } yield i -> j

  allIndexes.find {
    case (i, j) => (nums(i) + nums(j)) == target
  }
}
```

*(**Note:** `ArraySeq` is like any normal array, but it is immutable, it was introduced in `2.13` if you are in an older version, just use a regular `Array`)*.

Comment: really appreciated for your response

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own take, the function loops through all pairs of numbers until an answer is found. It makes use of scala's optimised recursion capability. Also it uses simple concepts only, useful for beginners: functions, Arrays, Ints and if-else statements.

```
def twoSum(nums :Array[Int], target : Int): Array[Int] = {
    def iter(a:Int, b: Int): Array[Int] = {
        if(nums(a) + nums(b) == target) Array(a,b) 
        else if(b < nums.length-1) iter(a,b+1)  
        else iter(a+1,a+2)
    }
    iter(0,1) 
}
```

jwvh: true. with empty array on failure:

```
def twoSum(nums: Array[Int], target: Int): Array[Int] = {
    def iter(a: Int,b: Int): Array[Int] = {
        if(nums(a) + nums(b) == target) Array(a,b) 
        else if(b < nums.length-1) iter(a,b+1)  
        else if(a < nums.length-2) iter(a+1,a+2)
        else Array()
    }
    iter(0,1)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to the community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who may not be familiar with the syntax. Further, it can help reduce the need for follow-up questions. Can you edit it to provide further explanation?