# Estimate Big-O for Two Sum Problem solution in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, recursion, big-o

I'm trying to estimate Big-O time and space complexity for the following solutions for a trivial [Two Sum Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/).
In my understanding, tailrec recursion should be a better solution, but when I try to determine the complexity, it looks like both of them have O(n) for time and O(n) for space.

```
inputArray = Array(4, 6, 5)
sumToCheck = 9
```

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

def checkTwoSum(inputArray: Array[Int], sumToCheck: Int): Boolean = {
  val subtractList: ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer.empty
  var output = false
  for (i <- inputArray.indices) {
    if (subtractList.contains(inputArray(i))) {
      output = true
    }
    else {
      subtractList += sumToCheck - inputArray(i)
      }
  }
  output
}

def checkTwoSumRec(inputArray: Array[Int], sumToCheck: Int): Boolean = {

  @tailrec
  def inner(input: Array[Int], subtractList: Array[Int] = Array.emptyIntArray): Boolean = {
    if (input.isEmpty) {
      false
    }
    else if (subtractList.contains(Option(input.head).getOrElse(0))) {
      true
    }
    else {
      inner(input.tail, subtractList :+ (sumToCheck - Option(input.head).getOrElse(0)))
    }

  }

  inner(inputArray)

}
```

Could someone please give a hint if that's true?

Comment: Here is a idiomatic and efficient solution to that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59620991/4111404

Comment: If not sure, you could just try different sizes of input and profile the runtime. Than make a plot to get an idea what complexity it might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things here:

1. Both of those solutions are `O(n^2)` time complexity. Notice that `contains` on lists is `O(n)` and since you can use it `n` times, the complexity becomes `O(n*n)`. A faster solution should use `Map`.
2. Tail recursion is usually better because it's a nicer way to write code i.e. it's harder to make mistakes. So recursion vs iteration is more about maintainability and readability of code and less about speed. (In Scala tail recursive functions are rewritten to `while` loops)
3. `Option(input.head).getOrElse(0)` is not safe. `input.head` throws a `NoSuchElementException` on empty list. So if you're sure that `input` is non-empty then simply use `input.head` and if you're not sure then use `input.headOption` and pattern match on it.

Comment: Tail-recursion also can be optimized to avoid stack usage which can be a significant amount  of memory usage for recursive algorithms. So its not only about readability. It also reduces memory usage and also improves speed when transformed to a loop (done by most compilers).